# Firefox Android ignores click event when tapping element while oncsreen keyboard is open

Tags: javascript, android, html, firefox

When typing into a text box with the on-screen keyboard and then tapping on a clickable element while the keyboard is still open

- the on-screen keyboard disappears as expected
- the tap is ignored, I see in the debugger that the click event handler isn't even reached
- tapping on the clickable element again, it now works as designed.

Tapping on other elements on the page with a click event handler while the keyboard is open works fine. One difference is that the unclickable button comes up only while typing, as it is in an autocomplete dropdown, a `<ul>` element switched visible by removing `display: none` after the third character is typed.

This happens on Firefox for Android, recent versions. It works in Chrome. Safari on iPad works, but only since the recent 16.x upgrade.

This looks like a weird browser vs platform quirk. Does anyone happen to know a workaround or can even explain some background

EDIT after further experimentation I have a fairly minimal [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ekc93sx/2/) to demonstrate the problem. It seems that Firefox on Android ignores click handlers which are attached to HTML elements created while the on-screen keyboard is open. Wouldn't mind if someone could confirm in a comment that I am not alone with my FF while waiting on an answer from someone in the know.